# How to change the checked status of radio buttons in a row on button click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a javascript function which on click change the radio button arranged in such a way that each row of the table has 3 radio button with value 1,2,3 and I have two buttons forward and backward. on click of a forward button if the found value of checked radio button is less than 3 then it is unchecked and the next radio button is checked i.e. if it is initially 2 then now due to forward click is 3 (this is now checked and 2 is unchecked).

Just focus on `forwardclick()` function once it executed then `backwardclick()` function will also be solved. Same case with the backward button.

Initially output

[Initial condition picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrwrv.png)

On click of the forward button

[Final Condition picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaT2b.png)

I have tried many things only lacking some functionality. Please correct me. Thanks

Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border=1>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr>

<td><input type='radio' name=row_1[] value='1' checked></td>
<td><input type='radio' name=row_1[] value='2' ></td>
<td><input type='radio' name=row_1[] value='3' ></td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td><input type='radio' name=row_2[] value='1' ></td>
<td><input type='radio' name=row_2[] value='2' checked></td>
<td><input type='radio' name=row_2[] value='3' ></td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td><input type='radio' name=row_3[] value='1' checked></td>
<td><input type='radio' name=row_3[] value='2' ></td>
<td><input type='radio' name=row_3[] value='3' ></td>
</tr>

<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>

</table>

<br><br>

<button onclick="backwardclick();">backward</button>
<button onclick="forwardclick();">forward</button>


<script>
function forwardclick() {
            var trtags = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

            for (var x = 0; x < trtags.length; x++) {

                if(x>=2){

                var tdtags = trtags[x].querySelectorAll("td");

                for (var y = 0; y < tdtags.length; y++){

                       var td = tdtags[y].querySelector("input[type=radio]")

                        // check td value if equal to 3 then no forward else increment the value by 1 and checked that radio button.

                        if(td.value != 3){

                            var status = td.value

                            td.checked = false

                            status = status + 1
                            // whenever it is found that td.value is equal to incremented status value that td is checked.

                            var tdtagsp = trtags[x].querySelectorAll("td")

                            for (var p = 0; p < tdtagsp.length; p++){

                                   var td = tdtagsp[p].querySelector("input[type=radio]")

                                   if(status == td.value){

                                    td.checked = true

                                   }else{

                                    td.checked = false

                                   }

                               }

                        }




                    } // end of for loop of tdtags



                   }// end of if (x>=2)

                }// end of for loop of trtags




        }// end function

        function backwardclick() {

            var trtags = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

            for (var x = 0; x < trtags.length; x++) {

                if(x>=2){

                var tdtags = trtags[x].querySelectorAll("td");

                for (var y = 0; y < tdtags.length; y++){

                    var td = tdtags[y].querySelector("input[type=radio]")

                    if(td.checked){
                    document.write(" checked ")
                    document.write(td.value)
                    }
                    else{
                    document.write(" unchecked ")                    
                    }


                    } // end of for loop of tdtags

                    document.write("<td>")

                   }// end of if (x>=2)

                }// end of for loop of trtags

        }// end function
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add minimal code so that one can understand , rather than posting everything.

Comment: Hi actual problem i not posted this is short version of problem only needs to modify the javascript function as required.

Comment: what minimal code do you need i tried by best to shorten the problem and keeping best in explaination

Comment: Also delete the previous question. Its not great to have more than one question with same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this solves your problem.

```js
  function forwardclick() {
            var trtags = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

            for (var x = 0; x < trtags.length; x++) {
                var inp = trtags[x].querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]")
                for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
                    if (inp[i].checked && i != 2) {
                        inp[i].checked = false;
                        inp[i + 1].checked = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  function backwardclick() {
            var trtags = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

            for (var x = 0; x < trtags.length; x++) {
                var inp = trtags[x].querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]")
                for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
                    if (inp[i].checked && i != 0) {
                        inp[i].checked = false;
                        inp[i - 1].checked = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
    <table border=1>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>

            <td><input type='radio' name=row_1[] value='1' checked></td>
            <td><input type='radio' name=row_1[] value='2'></td>
            <td><input type='radio' name=row_1[] value='3'></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><input type='radio' name=row_2[] value='1'></td>
            <td><input type='radio' name=row_2[] value='2' checked></td>
            <td><input type='radio' name=row_2[] value='3'></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><input type='radio' name=row_3[] value='1' checked></td>
            <td><input type='radio' name=row_3[] value='2'></td>
            <td><input type='radio' name=row_3[] value='3'></td>
        </tr>

        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>

    </table>

    <br><br>

    <button onclick="backwardclick();">backward</button>
    <button onclick="forwardclick();">forward</button>
```

Comment: checked radio are not moving on forward click button

Comment: please see at backward function if condition i m not able to figure out the if condition and break

Comment: @MyCreations What condition? Just check if `i != 0` and check the previous radio input

Comment: for `i != 0` it is not working as it is correctly working for forward click

Comment: @MyCreations  
Glad that i could help.
Also its better to delete your previous question as it is now of no use